# implicit conversion shortens 64 bit to 32 bit

Tags: iphone, floating-point, implicit-conversion, cgfloat

Can someone explain why this causes the error stated in the title?

```
CGFloat dx = fabs(lastPoint.x - currentPoint.x);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fabs()` returns a `double` (64-bit), but `CGFloat` is defined to be a `float` (32-bit). It's generally harmless – I personally would even disable the compiler warning, as performing calculations using `double` values is typically *at least* as fast as using `float` values.

Comment: "performing calculations using double values is typically at least as fast as using float values." are you sure about that on the ARM?

Comment: ARM has characteristics similar to PowerPC in that regard. As far as I know, both processors have to explicitly "shorten" floating-point values after performing calculations in order to pare them back down into floats before storing them in registers. The performance characteristics may not be the same in thumb code, though, where space is perhaps more important.

Comment: Aha, thanks!  I decided to cast to CGFloat which looks ugly in code.  Have never disabled a compiler warning tho?

Comment: @user7865437 If you don't like either of those solutions, floating-point functions are usually provided with `float` return values too. In this case, it'd be `fabsf()`.

Comment: So you mean use float rather than CGFloat?

Comment: No, I was referring to the fact that `float` and `CGFloat` are identical under the hood, so using a function that returns a `float` would eliminate that warning.

Comment: I'd like to update this answer: now `CGFloat` can be either `float` or `double` - basing on architecture (32/64bit).

Answer (score 2):

A better answer is to use `#include <tgmath.h>`. That header defines "adaptive" functions that call the correct function on whichever parameter size.

With that header included, you can simply call `fabs` without getting that warning (nor worrying about loss of precision caused by the use of the wrong function).